# Find Maximal values that can be acquired from N

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

There are n number of Houses (1,2,3,...,n). A thief have to start from house 1 and reach house n to steal the maximum. He can steal the house and he can leave. If at all he stole in any house, the house owner will inform the neighbors at the left and right. How much the maximum can he steal..

how can we solve by dynamic programming..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `arr[0..n-1]` denote the number of ports for each of the hosts from `1` to `n`.

At every point, you have two choices: to scan all the ports for the current host or to not scan the ports for the current host.

Let `dp[]` be resulting array.

Clearly,

`dp[i] = max(dp[i-1], arr[i] + dp[i-2])`

`dp[i-1]` for the case when you don't scan the ports. `arr[i] + dp[i-2]` when you scan the ports for the current host. In this case, you cannot add `dp[i-1]` due to the constraint that consecutive hosts can't be scanned. So we add `dp[i-2]`.

Your final answer is `dp[n-1]`

Hope it helps!!

**Edit**: Below is a question identical to yours:

*There are n houses built in a line, each of which contains some value in it. A thief is going to steal the maximal value in these houses, but he cannot steal in two adjacent houses because the owner of a stolen house will tell his two neighbors on the left and right side. What is the maximal stolen value?*

Find the solution [here](http://codercareer.blogspot.in/2013/02/no-44-maximal-stolen-values.html)